# ATA error count increased from 0 to 15 however Current_Pending_Sector is 0

Tags: smartctl

I got below error via an email 2 weeks back:

```
The following warning/error was logged by the smartd daemon:

Device: /dev/sda [SAT], ATA error count increased from 0 to 15

Device info:
ST1000LM035-1RK172, S/N:WCB0Z83A, WWN:5-000c50-09c2b85e7, FW:SBM3, 1.00 TB
```

I checked Smart data for the drive.

It shows: `Current_Pending_Sector` as 0

Also the self assessment seems to be fine:

`SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED`

I did not found any recent alerts in the syslog for past 1 week or so apart from this:

`Jun 19 22:44:37 raspberrypi smartd[416]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate changed from 80 to 81`

Below is the smartctl output:

```
<user>@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [armv7l-linux-5.10.42-v7+] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST1000LM035-1RK172
Serial Number:    WCB0Z83A
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 09c2b85e7
Firmware Version: SBM3
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Jun 22 21:26:47 2021 BST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

~
~

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   081   058   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       135782033
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   098   098   020    Old_age   Always       -       2845
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   097   097   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       1824
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   074   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       26398781
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       3868 (156 105 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   020    Old_age   Always       -       2449
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   085   085   000    Old_age   Always       -       15
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       77310590998
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   068   044   040    Old_age   Always       -       32 (Min/Max 32/33)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       11
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1447
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       13514
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   032   056   000    Old_age   Always       -       32 (0 16 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2953 (183 77 0)
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       6666012183
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       8609692665
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 15 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 15 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 53 hours (2 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 d5 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      04:02:06.187  READ DMA EXT
  b0 d5 01 c0 4f c2 00 00      04:02:06.178  SMART READ LOG
  b0 d5 01 00 4f c2 00 00      04:02:06.178  SMART READ LOG
  ef 03 46 f0 72 0f 00 00      04:02:06.165  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 03 0c f0 72 0f 00 00      04:02:06.154  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 14 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 53 hours (2 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      04:02:05.904  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      04:01:55.376  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      04:01:55.366  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      04:01:55.362  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      04:01:55.362  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 13 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 53 hours (2 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 d5 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      04:01:18.788  READ DMA EXT
  b0 d5 01 c0 4f c2 00 00      04:01:18.779  SMART READ LOG
  b0 d5 01 00 4f c2 00 00      04:01:18.779  SMART READ LOG
  ef 03 46 f0 55 c5 00 00      04:01:18.767  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 03 0c f0 55 c5 00 00      04:01:18.756  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 12 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 53 hours (2 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      04:01:18.534  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      04:01:18.529  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      04:01:18.443  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      04:01:18.442  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      04:01:18.442  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 11 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 53 hours (2 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 d5 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      04:01:18.095  READ DMA EXT
  b0 d5 01 c0 4f c2 00 00      04:01:18.084  SMART READ LOG
  b0 d5 01 00 4f c2 00 00      04:01:17.954  SMART READ LOG
  ef 03 46 98 54 c5 00 00      04:01:17.941  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 03 0c 98 54 c5 00 00      04:01:17.930  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2822         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Is it safe to continue using this HDD?

Comment: This drive was throwing errors two days after you first turned it on. It has not been safe to use at any time !

Comment: Thank alot for confirmation Michael, Took it offline for replacement !!